# iOS, how to display route between two points using Google Places Api?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, map-directions

I've been searching for **how to draw a route between two points using Google Places API in iOS**, but I have not found something interesting. The only way you can draw route between two points is to call web services and to parse JSON into your app, to route a route between two points.
[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) is a reference.

## The question :

Is there any sample code that can help me on how I can draw route between two points, an origin(based on user current location), and a destination.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this library](https://github.com/lukagabric/LRouteController), very powerful... with this you can draw directions between two points and much more

Answer (score 0):

You can get [this](https://github.com/ManoMarks/demos/tree/master/DirectionsAPIAsync) tutorial of a google developer for reference. And you can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdV7bCWuDYg&index=16&list=PL25BD62C6275E88F6) youtube tutorial for guidance.

Hope this helps. Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:30.692408
                                                            longitude:76.767556
                                                                 zoom:14];
    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    // Creates  markers in the center of the map.


    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.6936659,  76.77201819999999);
    marker.title = @"Chandigarh 47c";
    marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
    marker.map = mapView;

    GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.742138,  76.818756);
    marker1.title = @"Sukhna Lake";
    marker1.map = mapView;
    //creating a path

    GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
    [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@(30.6936659).doubleValue,@(76.77201819999999).doubleValue)];
    [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@(30.742138).doubleValue,@(76.818756).doubleValue)];

    GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    rectangle.strokeWidth = 2.f;
    rectangle.map = mapView;
    self.view=mapView;
 }
```

Comment: How does this answer this question?

Comment: Draws a straight line.