# direction between two markers in swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, direction

I want to get direction from google maps in swift.
In my application, user can make two markers with LongTouch and i want to show direction between markers and also i get latitude and longitude of each marker.
I am amateur and couldn't find code for this.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    if counterMarker < 2
    {
        counterMarker += 1
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop

        marker.map = mapView
        marker.position.latitude = coordinate.latitude
        marker.position.longitude = coordinate.longitude
        latitudeMarker = marker.position.latitude
        longitudeMarker = marker.position.longitude

        print(latitudeMarker)
        print(longitudeMarker)
        print("ok")

}
    }
```

how can I use google maps to get direction and time?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction), it is a service that calculates directions between locations using an HTTP request.

You can set your two markers as the origin and destination parameters, it is the address, textual latitude/longitude value, or place ID from which you wish to calculate directions.

- If you pass an address, the Directions service geocodes the string and converts it to a latitude/longitude coordinate to calculate directions.

> origin=24+Sussex+Drive+Ottawa+ON

- If you pass coordinates, they are used unchanged to calculate directions. Ensure that no space exists between the latitude and longitude values.

> origin=41.43206,-81.38992

For more information about Directions API, just read the link above for the documentation.

You can also try to check this related SO questions.

- [Google Maps iOS SDK, Getting Directions between 2 locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905797/google-maps-ios-sdk-getting-directions-between-2-locations)
- [Drawing Route Between Two Places on GMSMapView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550849/drawing-route-between-two-places-on-gmsmapview-in-ios?lq=1)
- [iOS, how to display route between two points using Google Places Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609043/ios-how-to-display-route-between-two-points-using-google-places-api)
- [How to draw a route between two locations using MapKit in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319643/how-to-draw-a-route-between-two-locations-using-mapkit-in-swift?rq=1)